# MemoryError for defaultdict(int)

Tags: python

I'm using a defaultdict(int) to record the number of word occurrences in a set of books.

Python is consuming 1.5 Gigs of ram when I get the Memory Exception:

```
  File "C:\Python32\lib\collections.py", line 540, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
MemoryError
```

and the size of my counter is over 8,000,000.

I have at least 20,000,000 unique words to count. What can I do to avoid the memory exception?

Comment: How many unique words are there in your data set?

Comment: Understood. And what's the average length of a word?

Comment: @NPE Somewhere in the order of 25.

Comment: Are all those words already read into memory?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I have the defaultdict(int) object defined outside my for loop which loops through the files and reads out the contexts. Within this for loop I then chop up the data into words, before storing them in a list. I then loop through this list and update the defaultdict. Therefore I'm presuming the garbage collector is cleaning up everything for each loop and that only the defaultdict is persistent.

Comment: I think you're pushing it given the algorithm and the data set at hand. Something needs a re-think (or you need more RAM + 64-bit Python). However, it's hard to make suggestions since we don't know what goes on in your code.

Comment: @Baz: That's what I am trying to verify, yes. Perhaps you can share that code with us? It is not necessarily the defaultdict that is the culprit here, it's merely the last drop in the bucket when it spilled over.

Comment: @NPE When you say you think I'm pushing it do you mean that it is my lack of RAM and/or my 32 bit processor that is the problem? If so, maybe I can change my algorithm so that I drop words that are only found once for a given book, since I really don't have a choice.

Comment: If you're sure your processor is 32-bit (and not just the Python), then it's definitely time to switch to using a database (one is included with Python).  I agree with @thkang that even on a 64-bit system, a database is probably better suited to your requirements.  But it doesn't hurt to try 64-bit Python if your hardware and operating system support it.

Answer (score 1):

even if you have a 64-bit system with loads of memory, I don't think it is a feasible idea to track them using a `dict`. you should use a database.

```
/* If we added a key, we can safely resize.  Otherwise just return!
 * If fill >= 2/3 size, adjust size.  Normally, this doubles or
 * quaduples the size, but it's also possible for the dict to shrink
 * (if ma_fill is much larger than ma_used, meaning a lot of dict
 * keys have been * deleted).
 *
 * Quadrupling the size improves average dictionary sparseness
 * (reducing collisions) at the cost of some memory and iteration
 * speed (which loops over every possible entry).  It also halves
 * the number of expensive resize operations in a growing dictionary.
 *
 * Very large dictionaries (over 50K items) use doubling instead.
 * This may help applications with severe memory constraints.
 */
if (!(mp->ma_used > n_used && mp->ma_fill*3 >= (mp->ma_mask+1)*2))
    return 0;
return dictresize(mp, (mp->ma_used > 50000 ? 2 : 4) * mp->ma_used);
```

from the [code](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/dictobject.c), it says that if you insert too much item, a dict has to grow - not only providing spaces for contained items, but also for slots for new items. it says if more than 2/3 of a dict is filled, a dict's size will be doubled(or quadrupled for less than 50,000 items). personally I use dicts to contain less than a few hundred thousand items. even with less than a million items, it consumes few gigabytes, almost freezing my 8gb win7 machine.

if you are simply counting items, you can :

```
spilt the words in chunk
count the words in each chunk
update the database
```

with reasonable chunk size, executing some db querys (assuming database access would be a bottleneck) will be much better imo.